# A very basic setting issue about spyder and anaconda for python

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am a beginner of spyder IDE for Python.

To use spyder IDE, I command "spyder" on anaconda console with python 2.7

After that, I try to print "hi"

But I encounter an error message

> "No python shell is currently selected to run hu.py Please select or open a new Python interpreter and try again"

How could I solve this problem?

I saved my file on C:\Anaconda\practice_jhk

```
from __future__ import print_function
print ("hi")
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to update the configuration of the IDE to point to `python.exe` or alternatively add `python.exe` to the environment `PATH`

Comment: thanks I will try. Should I add anaconda to the path? or add spyder to path? Actually I already added Python to path

Comment: Follow this url : http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the Spyder's Run Settings in Run -> Configure (F6). By default "Execute in current Python or IPython console" is selected and you probably do not have any open console in Spyder.

You can select "Execute in a new dedicated Python console" option and Spyder will automatically open a new console for you. Or you can leave the dafault option and create a new console yourself in the Consoles menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I am not able to fix it but I am able to successfully run the program the following two ways and I don't find any problems till now:

1. By selecting IPython console (not the one with the Kernel id as its tab) then running your program.
2. By selecting "Execute in new dedicated Python console" from Tools --> Preferences --> Run.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message, but then realized I was not directing the PATH to my Python interpreter file at all.  How I solved the problem:

Go to Tools > PYTHONPATH manager
Select "Add path"
Find and select your Python interpreter folder (for me this was C:\Python27)

Answer (score 1):

Try, tools -> Reset sypder to factory default. Then, click on the run button in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You might have unexpectedly closed the Ipython console window which is open by default and that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I didn't have the python console pane open.
To resolve this, in the top bar go to: **view -> panes** and turn ipython console on.

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Consoles > New console(default settings)